# How to find the next closes date in php from dd-mm-yyyy format?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Given today's date in the format dd-mm-yyyy
How would i find the next date from a string array with dates (of the same format) in the most efficient way.

The array has no order and it may contain dates prior to the given date.
Though I would like to have the soonest date close to the given date, but not form the past.

I have thought of first converting to a DateTime then  loop it through keep in memory one variable holding the soonest date which is just compared ("<") with the next date.

Is there a faster/better way in php?

Comment: Sort dates as timstamps, then take the following date after yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use unix time (strtotime).
So loop through the array and create a new array with each date as unix time.
Give it a try I have not tested it but in (my) theory it should work.

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   $new_arr[] = strtotime($value);
}

$nearest = closest($new_arr[], strtotime(time());
Echo date("d-m-Y",$nearest);

function closest($new_arr, $today) {
   sort($new_arr);
   foreach ($new_arr as $a) {
      if ($a >= $today) return $a;
   }
   return end($new_arr); 
}
```

Comment: @Zananok was that you upvoting? Does that mean it worked? I actually did not expect it to work at the first try.

Comment: It returned 01-01-1970
Edit: upvoted for showing me a different direction I haven't thought of exploring :)

Comment: Ops my mistake, it works perfectly (just note the missing brace on line 5 :) )

Comment: @Zananok Ahh! Nice! Didn't see that. Thanks!